# How to align VStack to top even if larger than height?

Tags: ios, swiftui, widget

I'm trying to create a widget that only allow `VStack` instead of `List`. I'm struggling with aligning the `VStack` to the top and letting the bottom truncate. It centres vertically and truncates both sides:

[image]

How can I make the `VStack` to the top so it starts from `1` and let it truncate from the bottom?

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/64291201/12299030?

Comment: It doesn't but figured it out and added my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found how to do this:

```
GeometryReader { geometry in
    VStack {...}
        .frame(height: geometry.size.height, alignment: .top)
}
```